# Regarding condition on code

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset of arrays. I want to take out those array whose values is lying in (0.5, 0.6).

I did it earlier for just less than 0.4

The code is

`c_subset = np.array(c)[np.where(np.array(c)<0.4)]`

Can anyone help to how to modify the above line to the interval condition?

Comment: Maybe:

`c_subset = np.array(c)[np.where(0.5<np.array(c)<0.6)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [numpy logical and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
>>> c = [0.50, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.60]
>>> a = np.array(c)
>>> a[(0.5 < a) & (a < 0.6)]
array([0.52, 0.54, 0.56,  0.58])
```

Note that [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If your original data doesn't use `numpy` and a simple list is sufficient on output, you can do this:

```
c_subset = [x for x in c if 0.5 < x < 0.6]
```